# Библиотека классов C#. Загрузка текстовых файлов в массив строк

Tags: c#, библиотека

Есть библиотека классов, которая использует большой массив строк. Эти строки должны загружаться из 4 текстовых файлов (текстовые файлы - постоянные, в них не вносятся изменения). Как лучше всего реализовать загрузку строк из файлов?

У меня пока они загружаются из ***приложения, использующего данную библиотеку***, а затем уже передаются как параметр через конструктор. Но этот способ мне не нравится, поскольку хотелось бы, чтобы библиотека классов была независимой и чтобы внутри библиотеки уже был заполнен этот массив строк.

**UPD 1**. Имеется ввиду, что строки должны загружаться **один раз**, например, сразу после запуска приложения. Есть вариант прописать в коде массив этих строк вручную, что-то похожее на:

```
private static readonly string[] words = {"first", "second", "third", ...}
```

Но, может, есть что-то получше?

Comment: Добавьте в ресурсы, и будет вам счастье :) в библиотеке естественно. Вариант 2: добавить в Settings, при этом выбрав StringCollections. Модное решение: собрать библиотеку на C/C++ которая отдает статические массивы, без явного выделения памяти.

Comment: @NewView именно к этому я и пришел сейчас) Когда задавал вопрос, почему-то не подумал про ресурсы. В итоге все оказалось просто: текстовый файл добавляется в ресурсы как строка, что очень удобно